# Should this be two separate lines?: `. echo "test" set dat = $dcmdir/$s/scan.log`

Tags: shell-script, scripting, tcsh

I'm looking at a `tcsh` script in which one of the lines is:

```
. echo "found scan.log, finding mprages" set dat = $dcmdir/$s/scan.log
```

That's all on one line. Is it feasible that this is actually valid, or does the stuff after the closing `"` have to be on a separate line?

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm new to this and am not wanting to make assumptions.

Comment: Does it really start with a `.`?

Comment: @jesse_b Indeed it does. It's in an `if` block if that makes a difference?

Comment: It looks like the original is [here](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/FsTutorial/Scripts#BatchProcessingwithrecon-all) - note the line above `#!/bin/tcsh -f (The above should be the first line of the script but # represents a comment in the formatted text, so it doesn't show up)`

Comment: @JamesRonald If it's part of a bigger block, could you post that block please?

Answer (score 1):

[That script has been significantly messed up](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/FsTutorial/Scripts?action=diff&rev1=15&rev2=16) by some wiki editing.  It's not valid as it currently stands.  [It used to look quite different](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/FsTutorial/Scripts?action=recall&rev=7#BatchProcessingwithrecon-all).

Answer (score 0):

set is an operator in the csh .

Is the echo version a script ? (but usually to load a module in csh you use the 'source' command.)

With regards to my mention of version of echo:
in classical UNIX most things which is used in a script is separate programs in the system, not a builtin of the shell (whether csh,zsh,sh (bourne),ksh (Korn) or tcsh (TENEX C Shell).)

The 'test' in bash (borne again bourne shell) is a builtin and so is echo while in some other versions of UNIX echo and test is separate binaries.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by "echo version". I did notice one thing thanks to your help though: would putting `#!/bin/tcsh -f ` at the top of a script make it be in csh/tcsh?